# Extract words between a word and a delimiter python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have extracted some text data from word document(.doc) and stored in a variable `my_text`
such that

```
my_text[2] = '2 Running Hrs                         -  \tPort M/E RPM  \t-  \t'
```

here **\t** is the delimiter from the document itself.
I'm trying to extract word/character between a word '*Running Hrs*' and '*\t*' a delimiter.
So that I would get an output '*-*'
Here I tried

1. **Trial 1**

---

```
import re
re.search('Running Hrs(.*)\t', my_text[2].strip()).group(1)
```

**Output**

```
 '                         -  \tPort M/E RPM  '
```

2. **Trial 2**

---

```
print(re.findall(r'\Running Hrs([^]\t*)\]', str(my_text[2])))
```

**output**

```
ERROR: error: bad escape \R
```

Any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first attempt is very close to what you want, as you just need to include a `?` flag to ensure your capturing group is non-greedy, like so:

```
r'Running Hrs(.*?)\t'
```

Without this `?` flag, your capturing group is considered greedy and will attempt to match as much as possible up until the last `\t`, whereas a non-greedy expression will only capture up until the first `\t`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this in your code

```py
start_phrase = 'Running Hrs'

start = my_text[2].index(start_phrase)+len(start_phrase)
end = my_text[2].index('\t')

my_text[2][start:end].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is nearly correct, but matches as many characters as possible (greedy behaviour). To have the minimial matching characters you may set the behaviour to non-greedy with '?' expression.

Also perform the .strip() after you have extracted the text between the start pattern and the '/t' to remove remaining blanks.

```
my_text[2] = '2 Running Hrs                         -  \tPort M/E RPM  \t-  \t'

import re
re.search('Running Hrs(.*?)\t', my_text[2]).group(1).strip()
```

see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want `-` as a result, I would suggest using strip in the result of `group(1)` instead.

If **\t** is the delimiter from the document itself, and there are no other occurrences of `\t` besides the one at the end, using strip on the whole line will remove that and the pattern will not match.

Instead of using the non greedy `.*?` you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^` instead, matching any char except a tab or a newline.

```
Running Hrs([^\t\r\n]+)\t
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XEehzQ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HZhMSW)

```
import re

my_text = '2 Running Hrs                         -  \tPort M/E RPM  \t-  \t'
print(re.search('Running Hrs([^\t\r\n]+)\t', my_text).group(1).strip())
```

Output

`-`